# Ubuntu 19.04 temporarily freezes on writing to disk

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, 19.04

I updated to Ubuntu 19.04 my corporate HP ProBook (16G RAM, two SSD disks: the first one, mounted on "/", is a 256 GB SSD, with encryption; the second one, mounted on "/opt", is 1TB Crucial MX SSD). Since the upgrade, everytime I download a file or save a new file on file system, after clicking on "Save" button, the entire system freezes for 5 to 10 seconds. The same doesn't happen if I save an existing file, so it doesn't seem to be related to every write operation.

Any idea about what's happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check for BIOS and SSD firmware updates at hp.com. Also contact your IT Dept.

Comment: Please add `dmesg` output to your question

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. I updated the BIOS to latest version (HP provides users with an utility which updates BIOS and firmware), but this didn't solve the issue. I'm going to add the dmesh output.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, quite new to AskUbuntu, I've just learned ([here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5932/how-can-i-attach-a-log-file-to-my-question)) that it's a better option to share a command output with pastebin service.
Here you can find the dmesg output: https://pastebin.com/mD71Bs2z

Answer (score 0):

Just another hint: it freezes also if I click on Cancel button, so it doesn't seem related to actually writing on disk.